# Absolute value in polar curves

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, absolute-value

I was graphing polar curves and I realized that the graphs of $r=3|sin(2t)|$, $r=3sin(2t)$ and $r=-3sin(2t)$ are the same. But the graphs of $r=2|cos(5t)|$, $r=2cos(5t)$ and $r=-2cos(5t)$ are different. Why?

Comment: How did you graph negative values of $r$?

Comment: @Klaus geogebra

Comment: What values of $t$ are you plotting?

Comment: I'm plotting $[0; 2 \pi]$